# Compatibility of Tizen and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ubuntu, tizen

I need to know if I can run an application under Tizen which uses the Chromium browser
in Kiosk/Fullscreen mode, nodejs, thttp (HTTP server), vsftpd (FTP servers) and unclutter (Hide Mouse Cursor).

Can I install+run all these packages (especially the Chromium browser and the nodejs) under
Tizen 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just install the packages available for Ubuntu, the answer is 'no'. You cannot just reuse this packages.

But you can compile these packages for Tizen if you have sources. It is much more complex. Here are some materials about compiling projects in C for Tizen using Tizen Studio:

- [helloworld](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/sdk-ide/how-do-i-compile-simeple-appliaction-like-helloworld.c-toolchain)
- [building applicaiton](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/native-application/application-development-process/building-applications)